# Window.print throws me an program stopping error

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdf.js

In my web application I am trying to print the contents of the screen. Although when I go to click the button to print, it throws me the following error

```
core.js:15714 ERROR Error: The overlay manager has not yet been initialized.
    at ensureOverlay (viewer.js:15555)
    at print (viewer.js:15449)
    at PrintCoverScanComponent.push../src/app/feature-modules/coverscan/component/print-coverscan.component.ts.PrintCoverScanComponent.printCoverPage (print-coverscan.component.ts:135)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (print-coverscan.component.ts:95)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
```

I have checked everywhere in google, but have found nothing. I've tried calling the function on load to be sure it wasn't the button causing anything.

```
<div *ngIf="!progressSpinnerEnabled" class="d-print-none">
        <hr />
        <button type="submit" style="float: right; margin-bottom: 10px;" nz-button nzType="primary" (click)="printCoverPage()">Print</button>
    </div>
```

```
printCoverPage() {
        window.print();
    }
```

**Additional info added by Stephan Rauh**: the application is using Mozilla's pdf.js (more precisely: `<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>`).

Comment: It could be an issue with the Browser Support. Which browser are you trying to run this on? Is there a minimal reproducible example that we can have a look at? Maybe a sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxvtch)?

Comment: It seems to not be working on Chrome and IE. I'm not sure how to give you a proper example as this application has a lot of pieces to it. I do not have a minimal reproducible example as of yet.

Comment: Which version of Chrome and IE are you trying to run this on?

Comment: Chrome is 75.0.3770.100 and IE is 11.253.17763.0

Comment: I can also reproduce it on my development machine which is using Chrome (75.0.3770.100)

Comment: I tested the `window.print` function on my machine on both these versions and they seem to work properly. This could have something to do with your business logic.

Comment: It's not a browser problem. Mozilla's library deliberately overrides the standard print function (see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/5517c94d66f22cc98df6dd1dab90ced15d49f3b8/web/pdf_print_service.js#L207). That shows that pdf.js has not been written with embedding in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 06/07/2019:** I've published a new version of `<ngx-extended-pdf-viewer>`. Please update to version 0.9.54 or above. This version stops overriding `window.print()` and fixes several other bugs related to printing.

**Original answer:**
ngx-extended-pdf-viewer author here. I wouldn't call it a bug, because the pdf.js team clearly intended to override the standard `print()` function. However, I have to admit that it's a bug in your application, so we should fix it.

I've started to work on the topic. I've published a preliminary bug fix with ngx-pdf-viewer 0.9.53. See https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/101 and how to activate the bug fix (it's only included in the developer preview).

I'll edit this answer again after successfully (or so I hope!) fixing the bug and bringing it to the main branch of ngx-extended-pdf-viewer.

Comment: Not important, but appreciated: if my answer really helped you, please upvote it. That's always a motivation boost to continue answering questions on StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had located the cause of the issue, it was a modification in the angular.json file. It seems there is a bug in the 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer' that I am using. Below is the modification that causes 'window.print()' to not work. 
[The left causes the error, the right fixes the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck6eK.png)

Comment: It's not really a bug. It's just an unexpected side effect of the underlying pdf.js library. Nonetheless, it's something to be fixed. Someone kindly opened an issue on our bugtracker: https://github.com/stephanrauh/ngx-extended-pdf-viewer/issues/101